# Comma inside quotes

Tags: punctuation, quotations

Is it correct to have a comma inside the quotes below for this excerpt from a story, or should it be outside?

> Bob wanted to see the world and meet other people; he would watch the planes fly past and thought, "Why can't I travel too," but he couldn't afford it, after all, he was only a young boy.

Comment: Hugely related and possibly a duplicate: [In British English is the comma correctly placed outside the ending quote mark in this sentence?](/q/352440)

Comment: In British English, the comma going inside isn't even an option. In American English, it depends on your style guide, but ideally it should go *neither* inside nor outside the closing quote, but *directly underneath* it, and it should do so for purely æsthetic reasons and no other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

There can be no comma - a questionmark is required.
"... he would watch the planes fly past and thought, "Why can't I travel too**?**" but he couldn't afford it[no comma] after all,

Comment: Apologies.  I was focusing on providing an example to ask whether the comma should be correctly placed outside the ending quote mark and missed the fact that it was a question.  With regards to the [no comma] you added, is this not a valid place for a pause comma?

Comment: Replacing the original comma after "afford" with a semicolon or dash might be better, but *some* punctuation needs to go there, don't just remove it.